# Front camera - Mirror and Rotate correctly before saving

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation, device-orientation, android-camera2

I want to mirror my image of the front camera before saving it to the sd-card. The thing is on some devices like Sony Xperia Z5 it rotates the image with 90 degrees as well after mirroring. 
I can't use the ExifInterface to get the orientation, because it requires a filepath and in my case i haven't saved it yet.

Is there any chance to get the orientation of the specific devices so i can rotate them properly?

Presetting:

- Camera2 Api
- Only Portrait Pictures

Comment: have you found a solution, I´m facing the same problem ;(

Answer (score 3):

In your captureBuilder, you have a parameter to set the "Orientation" of the image before it is taked:  `CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION`

[Android Developer website say:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html?hl=es#CONTROL_AE_MODE)

> The orientation for a JPEG image.
>
> The clockwise rotation angle in degrees, relative to the orientation
>   to the camera, that the JPEG picture needs to be rotated by, to be
>   viewed upright.
>
> Camera devices may either encode this value into the JPEG EXIF header,
>   or rotate the image data to match this orientation. When the image
>   data is rotated, the thumbnail data will also be rotated.
>
> Note that this orientation is relative to the orientation of the
>   camera sensor, given by android.sensor.orientation.

You can set this parameter in your CaptureBuilder:

```
 //To get the right orientation we must to get it in base of the sensor position.
 mSensorOrientation = getSensorOrientation();
 captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, mSensorOrientation);
```

Get your Sensor Orientation from your CameraCharacteristics, which you can get from CameraManager:

```
 public int getSensorOrientation() throws CameraAccessException {
    return mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId).get(
            CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
}
```

Hope that it will help you!

EDIT:
I attach you a method that I found long time ago to get the "real" orientation for a picture, depending of if you are in frontal camera, the sensor device orientation and the orientation that you want to get for your picture.

```
   public static int sensorToDeviceRotation(boolean mirror, int deviceOrientation, int sensorOrientation) {

    // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
    if (mirror) {
        deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;
    }
    // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
    // the image upright relative to the device orientation
    return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
}
```

Comment: thnx for your response. The thing is that i get the same rotations from the different devices. they are both 270 with the front camera. but only one device is adding a 90 degree to the image after adding the mirror matrix to the bitmap :(

Comment: what is device orientation? what it would be for portrait orientation?

Comment: snesor orientation is the position of ur phone sensor orientarion. you can get it from cameraCharacteristics. And device orientation is the orientation of the device when you tkae the photo(0,90,180,270). In your case, for portrait it should be 0(or maybe 180 if you have your phone rotated)